# Can we use the preposition "at" before the noun (hands)

Tags: grammar, prepositions, american-english, british-english, prepositional-phrases

I am a learner of English. Usually I use and see the prepositions *by* and *in* before the noun (hands). As these prepositions make sense when they come before the noun. But today I read an article on a news website. Where the reporter used the preposition *at* before the noun and it completely did not sound natural to me. So, as usual I landed here to get some help on it.

> On the news website:
>
> Ms Muhia says she would leave if her husband brought home another
>   woman, and that many others would do the same.
>
> "Where are we heading, we are going to have many divorces," she says.
>
> Some men clearly feel threatened by such talk. Nderitu Njoka, who runs
>   a men's empowerment group, says Kenyan men often suffer economic,
>   legal and even physical abuse **at the hands** of women - and he
>   defends polygamy.
>
> "If your first or second wife doesn't respect you as a man - does not
>   care for you, cook for you, do all those things that she's supposed to
>   do, then you're not supposed to just stay there and live a stressful
>   life."

Answer (score 2):

This is a metaphorical usage of [sense 16 in Collins for learners](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/at):

> You use at to say how something is being done.

In this case, *physical abuse at the hands of women* could be taken literally - that is, women may be using their hands to do this - but it is likely being used metaphorically, and means that women are responsible for the physical abuse.

In fact, it has its own [sense (#12) in Collins for learners](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-cobuild-learners/hand):

> If someone experiences a particular kind of treatment, especially unpleasant treatment, at the hands of a person or organization, they receive it from them.

In answer to your more general question about *at*: yes, you can use it with a noun.

- at home
- at school
- at the hospital
- at the side of the road

Comment: Thanks for cluing me into the Collins for Learners dictionary, I'm a native speaker but there are times when regular dictionary definitions don't provide as much context as I'd like.